# Japanese link parameter garbled in Struts2

Tags: url, struts2, urlencode, url-encoding, mojibake

I have this link in my Struts2 app:

```
<a href="/MyApp/My.action?w=%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89&key=6f98f58ce">Link</a>
```

`%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89` is shown as `言葉` in the browser status bar, which is good.

**PROBLEM:** When clicking on this link, Struts2's HttpRequest receives `w` as garbled text `è¨è` (seen with Eclipse debug). `w` is then printed to the JSP, where it shows as `è¨è` on the browser.

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Notes:

- HTML pages contain `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
- Chrome 16.0.912.63 on Ubuntu 2011.04

Comment: Is the JSP page encoding and servlet request encoding also set to UTF-8?

Comment: All JSPs contain `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`. Checking servlet request encoding now...

Comment: in place of the `<meta tag>` can you use `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>` and than let us know the outcome?

Comment: one solution which came to my mind is create a filter and place it in front of Dispatcher settler and let it handle the request data encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple filter that will do it.  You just need to add this filter
to your web.xml before the struts2 filter.

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
FilterChain next)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (encoding == null || encoding.length() == 0)
        {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        }

        next.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

not sure though it will work as have not tried it myself :)

**Update**

even after the above Filter i was also facing the same issue and after some digging it as per my understanding is due to the fact that application server will by default use the ISO 8859-1 character encoding.

i added the following entry in my tomcat server.xml file

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

URIEncoding="UTF-8"  // this is what i added
```

and now i am able to see the proper character in my jsp page.same we have to do with java default encoding.

read this great article [unicode-how-to-get-characters-right](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) by BalusC.

hope this will help you.

Comment: I added this filter and now: `<s:label>${w}</s:label>` shows empty, and `<s:label value="%{w}"></s:label>` shows è¨€è‘‰

Comment: yes i saw even on my machine the parameter in request is coming as `è¨€è‘‰`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still shows è¨€è‘‰ even after adding URIEncoding="UTF-8" and restarting the server.

Comment: That's strange i tested by removing the encoding from my tomcat's server.xml and problem again started moment i added it started working fine.Additionally i have following entry in my jsp files `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   %>`